# Get all MS Outlook Appointment Categories

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

I understand how to get the categories assigned to an individual appointment. From that, I can easily extrapolate how to get all of the categories assigned to any appointment in a calendar. However, there may be defined categories that aren't actually used for any appointments thusfar, I intend on still being able to capture these.

The end result is that my application should be able to present the user with a drop-down of all configured categories in MS Outlook. How would I go about doing this using interop?

So far I've looked through various classes contained within the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` library but I can't seem to find anything resembling a `.GetAvailableCategories()` method. Google has been a bit of a brick wall on this issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Namespace.Categories` collection. If you want categories from another store (e.g. a delegate Exchange mailbox), you can either read the hidden (associated) message from the default Calendar folder in that store (you can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - I am its author - click IMAPIFolder, go to the "Associated Contents" tab) or use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author): it exposes categories on the store level ([RDOPstStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).Categories, [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).Categories, etc.).